# 'Oversampling' cartesian data in a dataframe without for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample, smoothing

I have a 3D data in a pandas dataframe that I would like to 'oversample'/smooth by replacing the value at each x,y point with the average value of all the points that are within 5 units of that point. I can do it using a for loop like this (starting with a dataframe with three columns X,Y,Z):

```
import pandas as pd

Z_OS = []
X_OS = []
Y_OS = []
for inddex, row in df.iterrows():
    Z_OS += [df[(df['X'] > row['X']-5) & (df['X']<row['X']+5) & (df['Y'] > row['Y']-5) & (df1['Y']<row['Y']+5)]['Z'].mean()]
    X_OS += [row['X']]
    Y_OS += [row['Y']]

dict = {
    'X': X_OS,
    'Y': Y_OS,
    'Z': Z_OS
}
OSdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
```

but this method is very slow for large datasets and feels very 'unpythonic'. How could I do this without for loops? Is it possible via complex use of the groupby function?

Comment: Why `(df['Y'] > row['Y']-10)`? Is `10` a typo?

Comment: Do you mean something like moving average?

Comment: @Vitalizzare yes, that's a typo

Comment: @ShahabRahnama yes, like a 2D moving average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xy = df[['x','y']]
df['smoothed z'] = df[['z']].apply(
    lambda row: df['z'][(xy - xy.loc[row.name]).abs().lt(5).all(1)].mean(),
    axis=1
)
```

- Here I used `df[['z']]` to get a column 'z' as a *data frame*. We need an index of a row, i.e. `row.name`, when we apply a function to this column.
- `.abs().lt(5).all(1)` read as *absolut values which are all less then 5 along the row*.

---

**Update**

The code below is actually the same but seems more consistent as it addresses directly the index:

```
df.index.to_series().apply(lambda i: df.loc[(xy - xy.loc[i]).abs().lt(5).all(1), 'z'].mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column_name'].rolling(rolling_window).mean()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont understand how this applies to the problem. how could these be applied in 2D? The window would need to 'roll' over two columns and take the mean of a 3rd.